# MYSQL: подсчет количества строк в результате отфильтрованного с HAVING

Tags: mysql, count

Для примера есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
`quantity` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products_item` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`quantity` smallint(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Основной запрос, который возвращает результат:

```
select p.id, p.quantity, sum(pi.quantity) as pi_quantity
from products p
left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity)
```

Запускаю в Mysql-workbench в результате таблица из 48 строк.
Мне необходимо вычислить это количество. Я пробую так:

```
select count(*)
from products p
left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity)
```

Но это приводит к ошибке `"Unknown column 'p.quantity' in 'having clause'"`

Пока единственный рабочий вариант у меня в наличии это сделать так:

```
select count(*) from (
  select p.quantity
  from products p
  left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
  group by p.id
  having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity)
) t
```

Какие минусы такого подхода?

Так как же следует подсчитывать количество строк в результате в данном случае?

Спасибо.

Comment: чтобы выбирать по `quantity` в `having`, оно должно быть выбрано в `select`

Comment: @Mike, я хочу получить значение 48!

Comment: И в group by его добавьте. если даже mysql в текущей версии разрешит так сделать, то большинство других СУБД и новые версии MySQL не разрешают в having использовать колонки без агрегатных функций, не указанные в group by. или сделайте ход конем `having max(p.quantity) > sum(pi.quantity)`

Comment: @Mike, я согласен, что моя попытка вычислить количество таким способом неверна. Подскажите плиз как нужно вычислить  колисечтво в данном случае?

Comment: Все, теперь понял, что вы хотите ... `select count(1) from (select p.quantity from products p
left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
group by p.id
having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity) ) X`

Comment: @Mike, я как раз вопрос свой обновил)

Comment: @Mike, а что если вложенный запрос вернет ооочень большое количество строк? Переполнится память? Упадёт всё?

Comment: Если что то переполнится и упадет - это будет означать только баг в БД. По хорошему вас это вообще не должно заботить. БД сама разберется как выполнить ваш запрос, даже если в подзапросе будут миллионы строк, она может их например просто посчитать, предварительно нигде не сохраняя, или сохранить на диске, а потом посчитать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый способ, который вы и привели:

```
select count(1)
  from (
    select p.quantity
      from products p
      left join products_item pi on pi.product_id=p.id
     group by p.id
    having p.quantity > sum(pi.quantity)
  ) X
```

Правда смысла в LEFT join в данном случае я не вижу, потому что если в таблице products_item не окажется ни одной записи, то sum(pi.quantity) даст NULL и условие в having `p.quantity > NULL` не сработает. Если же записи где p.quantity больше нуля, а записей в pi нет, все таки следует получать, то условие надо исправить на `having p.quantity > coalesce(sum(pi.quantity),0)`. Особых минусов в таком подходе я не вижу.

Но так же есть и второй вариант:

```
select count(1)
  from products p
  left join (
      select product_id, sum(quantity) as sumQ
        from products_item
       group by product_id
  ) pi on pi.product_id=p.id
 where p.quantity > coalesce(pi.sumQ,0)
```

Особой разницы на самом деле я не вижу. Можно сравнить планы и время выполнения обоих вариантов и выбрать тот, что окажется лучше конкретно на ваших данных.

И третий вариант на всякий случай:

```
select count(1)
  from products p
 where quantity > (
         select colesce(sum(quantity),0)
           from products_item pi
          where pi.product_id=p.id
       )
```

Но такой подход даст выигрыш скорее в случаях, когда надо добавить дополнительные условия, которые отфильтруют часть продуктов до применения подзапроса.

Comment: Большое спасибо за примеры!